# HTML Move List To Side

Tags: html, css

I have this:

[image]

but I want it like this:

[image]

https://hastebin.com/qetowutage.xml

Also, ignore the white, that is nothing, that is just paint.

```css
.server_name {
  font-size: 50;
  padding-left: 5;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.001%;
}

.right_buttons {
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.option_button {
  padding-bottom: 20;
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: unset;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.option_text {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.server_options_button {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.server_options {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 500;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="server_name">Server_name</h1>
<ul class="right_buttons">
  <li class="option_button"><a href="#" class="option_text">Change Server</a></li>
  <li class="option_button"><a href="#" class="option_text">Log Out</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="server_options">
  <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Moderation</button></li>
  <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Music</button></li>
  <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Minecraft</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to see why this will be voted down and closed as off topic. Hint: Post effort and CODE in a [mcve]

Comment: Please show a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code [mcve]

Comment: Can you please add your current HTML.? A jsFiddle if you can.?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to add those white blocks... maybe creating some divs and changing the background color? I was being sarcastic.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly you are looking for? with some sample

Comment: I made a snippet with your code - It does not look like your pics

Comment: that is because it uses flask, and flask has special things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `margin-top: 10%;` instead of `padding-top:500` in `.server_options` in css

```css
.server_name {
  font-size: 50;
  padding-left: 5;
  z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.001%;
}

.right_buttons {
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.option_button {
  padding-bottom: 20;
  font-size: 30;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: unset;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.option_text {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.server_options_button {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.server_options {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10%;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="server_name">Server Name</h1>
  <ul class="right_buttons">
    <li class="option_button"><a href="#" class="option_text">Change Server</a></li>
    <li class="option_button"><a href="#" class="option_text">Log Out</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="server_options">
    <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Moderation</button></li>
    <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Music</button></li>
    <li class="server_options_button_ph"><button class="server_options_button">Minecraft</button></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Does not seem to have changed anything